# Could you help me find out what these tiles are in the following screenshot from a cartoon show?

Tags: logic

All I ended up finding were truchet tiles, so *are* these lines part of tessellating patterns or do they reference an entirely different thing?

[Screenshot from Space Dandy, Episode 11, depicting a hand holding a sheet of paper on which square tiles with quarter circles and other, interconnecting lines are drawn on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYIv0.jpg)

I am specifically looking for the "type", if you can call it that, of Math behind the patterns shown in the image, and if it is not just some nonsense that looks "mathematical", but really is just dressing to make it look more profound than it really is.

Help much appreciated, because since my 2d graphics class, I have caught a grid and pattern fever lately, that I want to explore further

Comment: Don't know if it's an appropriate question for this site, but they looks like braid groups

Comment: @Nikio thank you for your input, in layman's terms, I am trying to understand what it is I am seeing there, so that I can explain to someone else in such a way, that I can successfully communicate what I saw. I am already looking into knots right now thanks to you.